# HTML CSS auto size top bar

Tags: html, css, input, css-float

I want to make a "rubber" top bar, with ajax auto complite `div` which attached under `input` like that scheme:

```
<div1> ------- <a1><input   ><submit><a2> ------- <a3><div4>
                   <div5    >
```

When screen size is small it should be looks like:

```
<div1><a1>  <input   >
<submit><a2><div5  ><a3><div4>
```

Explains :

`<div1>` and `<a1>` small buttons one attached to the left size of screen, the second is attached to `<input>`

`<input> + <div5>` should be the same position and width, it means `<div5>` shows when something is typed and it is autocomple words, should overflow all under `<input>`

`<submit> + <a2>` buttons right after `<input>` after them whitespace till -

`<a3> + <div4>` are attached to the right side of the screen.

In small screen all after `<input>` should go next line.

The `HTML` is :

```
<div id="__topbar" class="_fixed">
    <div style="float:left">
        <div id="__attach" class="__whitebg" onclick="_action();"></div>
        <a id="__labelurl" class="__whitebg" href="url1.co">
            <div id="__imgurl"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <form id="postform" method="post" action="index.php">
        <div style="display:inherit">
            <input id="url" type="text" name="url" value="somevalue" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
                <div id="__livewrap">
                    <div id="__live"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="__go" value="go"> 
    <a class="__whitebg" href="url2.co">goto url2</a> 
    <a id="__home" class="__whitebg" href="/">
        <div id="__homeimg"></div>
    </a> 
    <div id="__godown" class="__whitebg" onclick="window.location.hash = '#footer'"></div>
    <br>
    </form>
</div>
```

`CSS` is:

```
#__topbar {
z-index: 99999;
width:100%;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
padding-top:4px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
#__labelurl {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
float: left;
}
#__imgurl {
background-image: url(img.png);
margin-right: 1px;
margin-top: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 18px;
width: 19px;
}
#__home {
border-radius: 7px;
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
}
#__livewrap {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
#__live {
position: relative;
background-color: white;
min-width: 400px;
width: 30%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#__homeimg {
background-image: url(img.png);
margin-right: 1px;
margin-top: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 18px;
width: 19px;
}
#__attach {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: left;
background-image: url(img.png);
}
#__godown {
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: right;
background-image: url(img.png);
}
#url {
max-width: 400px;
width: 80%;
}
#__go{
color: #2C5FCC;
background-color: #FFF;
border: solid 1px rgb(194, 194, 194);
border-radius: 7px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;   
}   
.__whitebg {
color: #2C5FCC;
border: solid 1px rgb(194, 194, 194);
background-color: white;
border-radius: 7px;
padding: 2px;
}
.__whitebg a{
color: #2C5FCC;
}
._absolute {
position : absolute;
}
._fixed {
position: fixed;
}
```

First problem that i cant attach `#__labelurl` (`a1`) to `<input`>

The second is when i changing window size elements are going down one by one and the `width` of `<input>` is different value which depends on `%` and how much elements are in the next line.

Thats why i cant get how to attach `<div5`> (`#__livewrap & #__live`) under `<input>`  (`#url`) to make their positions are same also as their width?

Is it possible to make what i want without `JS`? Or if its not i need to make it without `JQuery`

Comment: can you post js code please?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `JS` is not ready im working on it, he just add text to `#__live` `div`